# Why does Async.Start seemingly propagate uncatchable exceptions?

Tags: asynchronous, exception, f#, async-await

Consider this console app:

```
let throwAsync = 
  async { failwith "" }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  try Async.Start throwAsync
  with _ -> printfn "Failed"
  System.Console.Read() |> ignore
  0
```

The app crashes immediately when run. This doesn't make sense to me, for two reasons:

1. AFAIK (e.g. [this blog post](https://medium.com/jettech/f-async-guide-eb3c8a2d180a#0772)) exceptions should not bubble up through `Async.Start` (rendering the `try ... with` pointless, but it's there for point 2)
2. The (surprisingly) throwing code is surrounded by `try ... with`, but the exception is not caught (it never prints `"Failed"`, and again, the app crashes).

What's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception is thrown on a threadpool thread where the async block executes.

So yes, this means that the exception is not propagated to the thread that ran `Async.Start`, and the `try-with` block is never hit. But also, it means that the exception is now thrown elsewhere, and without any exception handling it will crash your app.

Quoting [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/the-managed-thread-pool):

> Unhandled exceptions in thread pool threads terminate the process. There are three exceptions to this rule:
>
> - A `System.Threading.ThreadAbortException` is thrown in a thread pool thread because `Thread.Abort` was called.
> - A `System.AppDomainUnloadedException` is thrown in a thread pool thread because the application domain is being unloaded.
> - The common language runtime or a host process terminates the thread.
>
> For more information, see [Exceptions in Managed Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/exceptions-in-managed-threads).

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that an exception will bring down an app that does not have any exception handling, regardless of the thread on which the exception is thrown? Also, do you know of a place I could read more about this?

Comment: Yes, an uncaught exception will bring down a .NET application, not sure of any places to dive into this further.

This `Async` guide may be of use to you though:
https://medium.com/jettech/f-async-guide-eb3c8a2d180a

Comment: @cmeeren: Added some more background on exceptions on thread pool threads.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

A `try` cannot catch an exception in an `async` when executed with `Async.Start` because they fork in different threads. If you want to catch it you can do so with `Async.RunSynchronously` or within another `async`:

```
let throwAsync = async { failwith "I was not caught!" }

let catchAsync = async {
    try 
        do! throwAsync
    with _-> printfn "caught inside async!"
}

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    try throwAsync |> Async.RunSynchronously 
    with _ -> printfn "caught outside!"
    try catchAsync |> Async.Start 
    with _ -> printfn "I did not catch it either!"
    System.Console.Read() |> ignore
    printfn "finishing!"
    0
```

output:

```
caught outside!
caught inside async!
finishing!
```

Comment: Thanks. As I said in the question, I know exceptions should not propagate across `Async.Start`, but my confusion was that the app crashed anyway. The answer by @scrwtp clarifies why.